# Returning Axios HEAD from Service wrapper class typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios

I am trying to return the head response through an Axios HTTP service wrapper.

axiosClass.ts

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from "axios";


class Http {
  private instance: AxiosInstance | null = null;

  private get http(): AxiosInstance {
    return this.instance != null ? this.instance : this.initHttp();
  }

  initHttp() {
    const http = axios.create({
      baseURL: "SOME API ROUTE"
    });

   
    this.instance = http;


    return http;
  }

   get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R> {
    return this.http.get<T, R>(url, config);
  }


  head<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R> {
    return this.http.head<T, R>(url, config);
  }

}

export const http = new Http();
```

fetch.ts

```
import { http } from "../vendors/axiosClass";

export type Article = {
  name: String
};

export const fetchArticle = async (name: String): Promise<Article[]> => {
  const { data } = await http.get<Article[]>("/works/" + name);
  return data;
};

export const fetchArticleHead = async (name: String): Promise<Article[]> => {
  const { data } = await http.head<Article[]>("/works/" + name);
  return data;
};
```

Calling the GET method (fetchArticle) will return a valid response, however, nothing is returned on the HEAD (fetchArticleHead)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the axios `head` method handler works according to the [standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) and just ignores HEAD body even if you're sending one.

From MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD):

> A response to a HEAD method should not have a body. If it has one anyway, that body must be ignored: any representation headers that might describe the erroneous body are instead assumed to describe the response which a similar GET request would have received.

Comment: There's likely nothing to ignore, because any most servers (i've seen at least) would never send one in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the answer to reflect it.